# How to set letter spacing of UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextfield

I have an app in which the user has to type a four digit pin code. All digits have to be at a set distance from each other.

Is there a way to do this if the `PinTextField` is a subclass of `UIView`? I know in a `ViewController` you could use `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification` and set the attributed text for each change. Notifications don't seem to work in a `UIView` though.

Also I was wondering if there isn't a simpler way than making an attributed string for every update if you want to set the letter spacing of a `UITextField` text ?

Correct spacing:

[image: TextField with correct spacing]

Wrong spacing:

[image: TextField with wrong spacing]

Comment: to begin with ***you have to use** a monospace font!!!!!

Comment: For anyone googling here, this has changed dramatically since this old question.  ***DO NOT*** use attributed text.  The solution is dead easy - look at @iOSer 's answer below.

Comment: Spacing is easy part, how do you draw the lines under the digits?

Comment: @Vakas i have same question did you found solution

Answer (score 75, accepted):

No need to go for **attributedText**, which to be honest, was a mess implementing with modified spacing. As soon as I closed the keyboard the spacing disappeared, which prompted me to dig further.

Every UITextField has a property called **defaultTextAttributes**, which according to Apple *"returns a dictionary of text attributes with default values."*. The [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619618-defaulttextattributes) also says that *"this property applies the specified attributes to the entire text of the text field"*

Just find a suitable place in your code, usually where the textfield is being initialized and then copy and paste the following.

Answered in Swift 3.0

```
textfield.defaultTextAttributes.updateValue(spacing, forKey: NSKernAttributeName)
```

where spacing is of CGFloat type. For example 2.0

This works for different fonts as well.

Cheers!!

---

The latest syntax seems to be:

```
 yourField.defaultTextAttributes.updateValue(36.0, 
     forKey: NSAttributedString.Key.kern)
```

Comment: @Fattie thank you for adding the latest syntax and for the comment as well. :)

Comment: If the TextField is secure then this solution is not working.

Comment: @Soumen sorry I have been busy with projects lately. But I will definitely look into this as soon as I get time. Thank btw for pointing that out

Comment: How to remove space from last text. I have to only feed 4 digit. In that case it will wrong.

Comment: @Ashu So you want three digits to be equally spaced and the last digit not so? Not sure what do you mean

Comment: @iOSer yes, last digit should not have extra space

Comment: Then Im afraid you'll have to use multiple texfields and take care of the spacing yourself.

Answer (score 12):

This is what eventually worked to set the kern for every change

```
    textField.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidChange", forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)

    func textFieldDidChange () {    
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: textField.text)
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSKernAttributeName, value: 5, range: NSMakeRange(0, count(textField.text)))
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: font, range: NSMakeRange(0, count(textField.text)))
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.blackColor(), range: NSMakeRange(0, count(textField.text)))

        textField.attributedText = attributedString
    }

    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        if count(textField.text) < 4 {
            return true
            // Else if 4 and delete is allowed
        }else if count(string) == 0 {
            return true
            // Else limit reached
        }else{
            return false
        }
    }
```

The problem however remains because different numbers have different widths, I will just resort back to making a `UITextField` for every digit.

Comment: The proper solution is to use monospace font.

Comment: Your entire second method can be nicely collapsed into one line:

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    string.isEmpty || count(textField.text) < 4
}

Answer (score 4):

Use the `defaultTextAttributes` property of `UITextField`. It will handle the conversion to `NSAttributedString` for you and apply the attributes you set. For example:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *attrs = [self.textField.defaultTextAttributes mutableCopy];
[attrs addEntriesFromDictionary:@{
    NSKernAttributeName: @18,
    NSUnderlineColorAttributeName: [UIColor grayColor],
    NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle | NSUnderlinePatternDash)
}];
self.textField.defaultTextAttributes = attrs;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure about any other solution instead of using attributed string.

But for the notification part, you can set the `textFields` delegate to `UIView` and define below method in the view.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;
```

The above method is called every time the text entered in the text field changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code After setting the delegate to the textfield.Hope it will work.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textField.text];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName
                             value:@(5.4)
                             range:NSMakeRange(0, textField.text.length)];
    textField.attributedText = attributedString;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` does not work for the first letter though, it only appears after you have input the second one.

Comment: check this link for first letter change, it may help you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010547/uitextfield-text-change-event

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine in Swift 2.2. Hope this will help you for letter spacing in text field

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SignupVC.limitTextField(_:)), name: "UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification", object: txtContactNumber)
}
 func limitTextField(Notif:NSNotification) {

    let limit=10;

    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: txtContactNumber.text!)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSKernAttributeName, value: 7, range: NSMakeRange(0, (txtContactNumber.text?.characters.count)!))
   // attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: font, range: NSMakeRange(0, count(textField.text)))
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.blackColor(), range: NSMakeRange(0,(txtContactNumber.text?.characters.count)!))

    txtContactNumber.attributedText = attributedString
    if(txtContactNumber.text?.characters.count>limit)
    {
        txtContactNumber.text=txtContactNumber.text?.substringToIndex(limit)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to count the kern for each character and remove it for the last character. There is example on Swift 5.3

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    
    let maxLength = 6
    let symbolWidth = CGFloat(43)
    let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)
    
    if string == "" { // when user remove text
        return true
    }
        
    if textField.text!.count + string.count - range.length > maxLength { // when user type extra text
        return false
    }
    
    let currentText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textField.attributedText ?? NSMutableAttributedString())
    currentText.deleteCharacters(in: range) // delete selected text
    var newStringLength = 0 
    
    for char in string{
        let newSymbol = NSMutableAttributedString(string: String(char))
        newSymbol.addAttribute(.font, value: font, range: NSMakeRange(0, 1))
        let currentSymbolWidth = newSymbol.size().width
        let kern = symbolWidth - currentSymbolWidth
        newSymbol.addAttribute(.kern, value: kern, range: NSMakeRange(0,1))
        
        currentText.insert(newSymbol, at: range.location + newStringLength)
        newStringLength += 1
    }
    
    if currentText.length == maxLength{
        currentText.addAttribute(.kern, value: 0, range: NSMakeRange(maxLength - 1, 1))
    }
    
    textField.attributedText = currentText
    
    return false

}
```